# Android Split Menu

Tags: android, menu

I'm trying to figure out if there's already some built in functionality in android to create a split menu (i'm not sure what to call it). What I want is to have a menu inside of an activity or fragment like this one: [image with split menu inside activity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CNB4M.png)

Please note that I don't want the split menu to be in the action bar. Any guidance or demonstration would be great.

Comment: http://www.androidhive.info/2015/09/android-material-design-working-with-tabs/

Comment: What, in that image, do you consider to be a "split menu inside activity"? I see two tabs, one of which contains a vertically-scrolling list (`ListView` or `RecyclerView`, most likely).

Comment: that's what I'm referring to, the two tabs

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya thanks! i wasn't sure what to search for. Post it as an answer and I'll mark it as correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Android 5.0 Lollipop was one of the most significant Android releases
>   ever, in no small part due to the introduction of material design, a
>   new design language that refreshed the entire Android experience.

You might have heard of android Material Design which was introduced in Android Lollipop version. In Material Design lot of new things were introduced like Material Theme .

For this requirement You can check below Demo . Hope this helps .

**[Android Material Design working with Tabs](http://www.androidhive.info/2015/09/android-material-design-working-with-tabs/)**

> http://www.google.com/design/spec/material-design/introduction.html